# Change a value in params hash before saving it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, strong-parameters

For some reason, this isn't working

```
user_params[:height] = user_params[:height].to_i * 100
User.new(user_params)
```

It just saves the "height" parameter as 1.8, when it should be 180 (in other words, it's not being changed as the code instructs).

How can we simply change a param in the params hash before saving the params hash?

#### what I've tried

I tried what's above

I also tried `user_params[:height] = (user_params[:height].to_i * 100).to_s`, but that didn't work either.

I can confirm it works on a normal hash:

```rb
h = {a: 1, b: 2}
=> {:a=>1, :b=>2}

h[:a] = h[:a] * 10
=> 10

h
=> {:a=>10, :b=>2}
```

So I can't work out why it won't work on the params hash

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a proper answer, because I cannot explain why it works, but I had to create a new hash for it to work:

Replace this:

```rb
user_params[:height] = user_params[:height].to_i * 100
User.new(user_params)
```

with this:

```rb
u = user_params.to_h
u[:height] = u[:height].to_i * 100
User.new(u)
```

Then it works as expected

Comment: also no answer, but here's an interesting read: [http://joshfrankel.me/blog/modifying-strong-parameter-values-after-a-request/](http://joshfrankel.me/blog/modifying-strong-parameter-values-after-a-request/)